# How to disable the scroll and have the site to fit the screen and not move.

Tags: html, css, slider

Hi can anyone help me with this website ...to disable the scroll .. I would like the page to be fixed and fit the screen but without any scroll, and move, please. http://ivyonestudio.co.uk/

Comment: You need to make some search by yourslef. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

update your CSS to include

```
html {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```